# select scroll issue with chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-chosen

I am facing a problem in select with chosen in chrome. I am moving the selected option of select but it doesn't scroll the select.

Works fine in other browsers ff, ie, safari etc

See the video here: http://screencast.com/t/tS5T4D4Vb

In this video, first I move the selected option in firefox, then do the same with chrome. I guess I am missing something. My chrome is 25.0.1364.97